# Replace text in string with delimeters using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a string something like,

```
string str = "(50%silicon +20%!(20%Gold + 80%Silver)| + 30%Alumnium)";
```

I need a Regular Expression which would Replace the contents in between ! and | with an empty string. The result should be `(50%silicon +20%  + 30%Alumnium)`.

If the string contains something like (with nested delimiters):

```
string str = "(50%silicon +20%!(80%Gold + 80%Silver + 20%!(20%Iron + 80%Silver)|)|
              + 30%Alumnium)";
```

The result should be `(50%silicon +20% + 30%Alumnium)` - ignoring the nested delimiters.

I've tried the following Regex, but it doesn't ignore the nesting:

```
Regex.Replace(str , @"!.+?\|", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: You should really work on your explanation and the formatting of your question.

Comment: Sure i will work on the things you mentioned.
Alex i tried the approach which is given below Regex.Replace(str , @"!.+?\|", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); The problem comes when the nested delimeters comes. Nested delimeters should just be ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the lazy quantifier `+?` which will look for the smallest possible substring that matches your regex. To get the result you are looking for, you want to use the greedy quantifier `+` which will match the largest substring possible.

The following regex (not tested in C# because I don't have it available, but this should work for any standard regex implementation) will do what you want:

`'!.+\|'`

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

str = Regex.Replace(str , @"!.+?\|", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: It is working. for the first part but fails in the second part.

Comment: Sure i will work on the things you mentioned.
Alex i tried the approach which is given below Regex.Replace(str , @"!.+?\|", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); but the problem comes when there are nested delimeters. Nested delimeter should just be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Regex.Replace(str, @"!.+?\||\)\|", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Works for both provided strings. I extended the regex with a 2nd check on ")/" to replace the leftover characters.